# What is the difference between 'so that' and 'as'?

Tags: grammar

Which statement is grammatically wrong and why?

1. She read the agreement *as* she would make sure there was nothing wrong in it.
2. She read the agreement *so that* she would make sure there was nothing wrong in it.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is incorrect. In this usage, "as" denotes "to the same degree" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as). It would be more appropriate therefore to use "as" to describe **how** not why, e.g., "She read the agreement as if her life depending on it, making sure there was nothing wrong with it."

The second statement correctly uses "so that" to describe **why**. In that case, I would suggest the simplified, "She read the agreement to make sure nothing was wrong."

Comment: The first statement can be interpreted in a correct way:  _as_ can be used in place of _because_, eg _I eat something, as I am hungry._

Comment: The first sentence would only be correct if rephrased to something like: *She read the agreement, as she* ***wanted to*** *make sure there was nothing wrong with it.* Note the addition of the comma and changed words.